# Compiled program can't find files

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard

```
NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];   
NSString *pathToFile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sells", [fm currentDirectoryPath]];
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:pathToFile] == NO)
{
    return NO;
}
else
{
    if(content)
    {
        [content release];  
    }
    content=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
return YES;
```

It works normally in XCode, but my.app always return NO ("sells" exists in it's directory of course). How to solve it?

Comment: Do you know what the current directory of a running app is?  If these files are within your bundle then you need to get the bundle path not the current directory.

Comment: Right, you hardly ever use currentDirectoryPath on iPhone.  It's there mainly for hysterical reasons.

Comment: Even if     NSString *pathToFile=[NSString stringWithString:@"sells"]; (file is in the same directory with app) it returns NO :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how you normally access a single file in the App bundle:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"ext"];  
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

And this is how you should access a directory:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName"];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        // foo bar
    }
```